# SignalR Can I pass a DataSet

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have a SignalR application in two parts. I have basic messaging going back and forth between an MVC app (SignalR Server) and the Windows Service (SignalR Client). The Windows Service is on a back-end machine that has the AdventureWork2012 database on  it. Management desires that the Windows Service - SignalR client query the database and send back a DataSet via SignalR. Can SignalR pass DataSets? I am getting an exception "Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long." in the event log when I call the server method.

Here is the MVC Server Hub:

```
public class AlphaHub : Hub
    {
        public void Hello(string message)
        {
            // We got the string from the Windows Service 
            // using SignalR. Now need to send to the clients
            Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage(message);

            // Call Windows Service
            string message1 = System.Environment.MachineName;
            Clients.All.Notify(message1);


        }
        public void Register(string registrationID,string connectionID)
        {
            // We got the string from the Windows Service 
            // using SignalR. Now need to send to the clients
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["registrationID"] = registrationID + "|" + connectionID;
        }

        public void RecieveDataSet(DataSet ds)
        {
            Clients.All.addNewMessageToPage("Data Set recieved");
        }
```

Here is the Windows Service Code that throws an exception on the line:

```
await alphaProxy.Invoke("RecieveDataSet", employees);
```

The code is:

```
protected override async void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("In OnStart");
            try
            {
                var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://www.someurl.com/signalr", useDefaultUrl: false);
                IHubProxy alphaProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("AlphaHub");

                await hubConnection.Start();
                string cid = hubConnection.ConnectionId.ToString();
                eventLog1.WriteEntry("ConnectionID: " + cid);
                // Invoke method on hub

                await alphaProxy.Invoke("Hello", "Message from Service - ConnectionID: " + cid + " - " + System.Environment.MachineName.ToString() + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
                await
                    alphaProxy.Invoke("Register", "81577f58-0e05-43f4-b322-fbf0d9d1e79e",
                        hubConnection.ConnectionId.ToString());


                alphaProxy.On("addNewMessageToPage", () =>   eventLog1.WriteEntry("Notified!"));

                DataSet employees = new DataSet();
                string connString = "...";
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
                string queryString = "SELECT * FROM [HumanResources].[Employee]";
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(queryString, conn);
                adapter.Fill(employees, "HumanResources.Employee");

                await alphaProxy.Invoke("RecieveDataSet", employees);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                eventLog1.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Is it possible to pass a DataSet? If not, do I have to serialize/deserialize? If so, can you show the code to do that?

Comment: You can pass a json object to your javascript yes.

Comment: I am not dealing with JavaScript here. I am trying to call RecieveDataSet on the Hub class in the server.

Comment: As long as you can generate JSON, you can send it I believe.

Comment: I understand that I can send JSON to clients that are JavaScript. That is not the use case here. Please re-read the use case.

Comment: I think what @AD.Net is trying to tell you is to serialize as JSON anyway. Send the data as JSON, then deserialize into whatever (DataSet, etc) on the Hub.

Comment: Have you looked what's on the wire? Is the data getting pushed into the URL because SignalR is falling back to JSONP maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you convert your dataset into a Data Transfer Object and pass that. With SignalR, you could pass each object as it is hydrated allowing you to notify observers not only when you fetch, but also whenever any new item is added as well. I haven't tested this code, so I may well have missed something, but it should give you the idea.

```
adapter.Fill(employees, "HumanResources.Employee");
foreach (var dr in employees)
{
   var empDto = new EmployeeDto
   {
       FirstName = dr.Fields("FirstName"),
       LastName = dr.Fields("LastName"),
       // Additional fields go here...
   };
   alphaProxy.Clients.ReceiveDataSet(empDto); // Serializes the dto as json by default.
}
```

Of course, if you want to send the full list in the response you should be able to modify this slightly:

```
adapter.Fill(employees, "HumanResources.Employee");
var items = new List<EmployeeDto>();
foreach (var dr in employees)
{
   var empDto = new EmployeeDto
   {
       FirstName = dr.Fields("FirstName"),
       LastName = dr.Fields("LastName"),
       // Additional fields go here...
   };
   items.Add(empDto);
}
alphaProxy.Clients.ReceiveDataSet(items); // Serializes the dto as json array by default.
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to keep your messages pretty lightweight with SignalR for many reasons (especially with scale-out via backplanes), so I would NOT pass something big like a `DataSet` via a SignalR message personally. What I usually suggest for larger payloads is that you send a specific message that tells the browser it should update that data which it then does by downloading using a traditional GET to some kind of REST based service. This way you have real-time notifications of updates, but you're using traditional HTTP GET to transfer the actual payload.

Comment: Guess it depends how the Dataset is packaged. If I rememeber right JSON serialization produces just the data for a DataSet and it's no more verbose than a collection of objects. Not sure if this is supported by SignalR tho. JSON.NET does (one way only though).

Comment: Yeah, but I think what it boils down to is, regardless of "shape", the overall size of the payload. If there's one row/entity with a few columns/properties, ok... "whatevs". If it's gonna be 10+ rows/entities, odds are it should not be getting transported via a SignalR msg and instead the SignalR message should point to some REST URL to say "hey, this changed, go check yourself". Right tool for the job.